# Mounting external hard drive using LUKS2 and FIDO2 Key

Tags: fedora, luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

I have encrypted an external hard drive using LUKS2 on my machine running Fedora 34 using the `cryptsetup` command.

When I now plug in the hard drive and enter the passphrase, the drive is unlocked successfully, and I can access my files.
Additionally, I'd like to be able to unlock the drive using my FIDO2 security key.
I have added the key as an unlock option using this command:

```bsh
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --fido2-device=auto /dev/sdc1
```

In the documentation for the `/etc/crypttab` file, I found out how to automatically unlock such a drive during boot.

Unfortunately, I did not find any documentation how to unlock such a drive manually using the FIDO2 key. When I try to unlock it using `cryptsetup open /dev/sdc1 myLuks`, I have to enter the passphrase. In the manual for `cryptsetup` I could not find a parameter similar to `--fido2-device` either.

Can someone explain how to unlock a LUKS2 encrypted drive manually using a FIDO2 key?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to manually unlock the device with `systemd-cryptsetup`

```
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach myLuks /dev/sdc1 - fido2-device=auto
```

You can't use `cryptsetup` to unlock LUKS devices using FIDO (or TPM2) right now, support for these is in systemd only (it uses LUKS2 feature which allows adding "foreign" metadata to the LUKS header, but the code to work with FIDO/TPM2 is only in systemd so cryptsetup doesn't know how to get the key from FIDO/TPM2). This will change, cryptsetup 2.4.0 (not released yet, RC0 is currently available in Fedora Rawhide and Debian Experimental) adds a new plugin interface and it will be possible to use `cryptsetup open` to automatically open the device using FIDO/TMP2 (and other "tokens" supported by systemd) in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does seem to be the correct command, but unfortunately, it fails due to an error.

I performed the command you suggested and got the following output (and was asked for the passphrase again):

```Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 512 bits for device /dev/sdc1.

Automatically discovered security FIDO2 token unlocks volume.

Asking FIDO2 token for authentication.

Failed to activate with FIDO2 decrypted key. (Key incorrect?)

 Please enter passphrase for disk <my disk model> (myLuks): (press TAB for no echo) 
```

Comment: While setting up the key, I had to enter the pin and press the physical button. Now to unlock it, it did not ask for the pin at all. I'm using systemd 248 (v248.4-1.fc34) if that is relevant.

Comment: I think you are hitting the same issue that's [described here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/19252), but I'm not 100 % sure (at least the result and error message is the same). The [fix linked to the issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/19298) is available only in systemd 249 (which is not available in F34).

Comment: Then I guess I'll wait until systemd 249 hits Fedora 34 or give it a try in a VM with systemd 249 installed. 
I'll mark your answer as accepted because this is definitely the way it should work (without the issue in v248). Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have compiled and installed systemd 249 on a Fedora 34 machine and can confirm that it worked flawlessly. I hope the new systemd will be available in Fedora 34 in the future. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Since cryptsetup >= 2.4 is now available (e.g. on Fedora 35), are there any options one should specify to use it with the plugin interface (i.e. to unlock Fido2 slots) - or should that work automagically?

Answer (score 2):

In fedora 37 cryptsetup 2.5.0 the following works:

```
sudo cryptsetup open --token-only  /dev/sdb1 myLuks
```